# distinguish header files from compiler/language standard/os/glibc

Tags: c++, c, linux, clang

There are lot of header files in `/usr/include`, and some elsewhere.

Some headers come from the C language standard, like `stdint.h`.  Some come from the compiler, some are for glibc.

How should I distinguish them, because being sure of their antecedents can help me to reasoning/understanding some things...

Comment: The best way to know if something is in the standard or not is to get a copy of the standard, and search through it.  Anything not mentioned in the standard isn't from the standard.  :-)  Other than that it's [caveat emptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveat_emptor)

Comment: tks,i will read the standard,and then ask for help

Answer (score 1):

You will find some common patterns:

- bits/ - implementation details, you should not use these directly
- linux/ - OS-specific stuff, might be needed once in a while
- netinet/ - "Internet" stuff, IPv4, TCP (IPv6 is in netinet6/ on some systems)
- gcc/ - obvious, usually you wouldn't go here
- c++/ - obvious, usually your C++ compiler should include this by default so you use it implicitly
- /usr/local/include/ - stuff installed on your system by the administrator that the distribution didn't provide on its own or via its package manager
- foo/ - often a particular "foo" library (aka libfoo) will put this under /usr/include/

Comment: netinet/ isn't just IPv4, but general TCP/IP, excepting the hardware and application layers.

Comment: @John Zwinck,does headers for glibc reside in OS-specific dir? tks

Comment: @basketballnewbie: No, not generally, to my knowledge.  glibc implements a lot of standard things which you'd expect to find directly under /usr/include/.